# django-compressor with s3 and sass

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-compressor

I am using AWS EC2 to serve my Django app that uses in turn django-compressor to compress js and css files, and uses S3 as the STATIC_ROOT.

I am also using SASS with django-compressor so it is supposed to compile and compress SCSS files.
But, when I am executing the command `python manage.py compress --force` I can see that there is an error -

```
error No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /var/www/django/myapp/https
```

it seems as though instead of understanding that the input file path is https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/etc...
it tries to resolve a relative path..

I have used the `CssAbsoluteFilter` recommended and I am quite frustrated because this is a weird behavior.

Of course, `DEBUG=False` and `COMPRESS_ENABLED=True`.

Any help?